# Dimension for very large designs

Tags: adobe-photoshop, fonts, dimensions

I'm working on a design which is to be printed and displayed on a 8ft by 2.32ft. What dimension can I use when using photoshop because I can't find any fonts that can extend that large. Thanks.

Comment: To answer the part of your question not covered by the duplicate: you are not limited to the point size values in the drop-down: click the current value, and key in your own.

Answer (score -1):

Is your design purely vector-based, or will you be using raster images? If you are submitting your file to the printer as a vector file (PDF is generally the best way to go), you could create a 8" x 2.32" file which could be easily scaled up, with no loss in resolution if it uses only vector files. If you are also using raster images, (JPEG files, etc.), you could create your file in Photoshop with a pixel count per inch higher than 300 (for the size you mentioned, 3600 pixels per inch would be required for a 300ppi result).

This assumes, of course, neither InDesign or Illustrator are options, which I personally find better suited for that type of project.